# Is there any Alternative Package Available for ZXing.Net.Mobile while Migrating From Xamarin IOS to .NET 7 IOS?

Tags: .net, barcode-scanner, visual-studio-mac, zxing.net.mobile, .net-ios

I can see my Existing Barcode Scan Package(ZXing.Net.Mobile - 2.4.1) does not support .Net 7 IOS Platform.

I ve been using this for Xamarin IOS earlier. Now after Migration its not supporing.

I was looking for workaround for this and tried other packages like :

1. ZXing.Net.Maui - This is not stable Version(Only latest Preview Release) and is .Net MAUI Specific Package.
2. ZXing.Net6.Mobile - This is not stable Version(Only latest Alpha Release) and does not have .Net 7 IOS Support.

https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Maui/issues/130
https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Maui/issues/106

Please check attached screenshots for this
[This is Image of Zxing.Net6.Mobile showing only .Net 6 IOS Support and is Alpha Release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bUjY.png)
[This is Image of Zxing.Net.Maui showing preview release and has only MAUI Support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BtQ6.png)
[This is Image of Zxing.Net.Mobile - 2.4.1 showing no Support for .Net 7 IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czb7L.png)